# fetching a webpage using java socket class

Tags: java, networking, client-server

Good evening to all of you

I want to fetch a webpage using the socket class in java and i have done this as

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class htmlPageFetch{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                try{
                        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 80);
                        DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                        DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        dOut.write("GET /index.php HTTP/1.0\n\n".getBytes());
                        boolean more_data = true;
                        String str;
                        while(more_data){
                                str = dIn.readLine();
if(str==null)
more_data = false;
                                System.out.println(str);
                        }
                }catch(IOException e){

                }
        }
}
```

But it is just giving the null's.

Output

```
 HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 01 Dec 2010 13:49:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8k PHP/5.2.9 mod_apreq2-20051231/2.6.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
Location: http://localhost/xampp/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html

null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is causing your problem, but HTTP expects carriage return and line feed for a newline:

```
dOut.write("GET /index.php HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
```

Also, it wouldn't hurt to flush and close your DataOutputStream:

```
dOut.flush();
dOut.close();
```

If you plan on doing anything more with this code than just connecting to simple test cases, I'd recommending using HttpURLConnection for this instead of implenting HTTP in a socket yourself. Otherwise, the result will contain more than just the web page. It will also contain the HTTP response including status codes and headers. Your code would need to parse that.

**Update:**

Looking at the response you added, that 302 response along with the Location: header indicate that the page you are looking for moved to http://localhost/xampp/ (see [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)) and there is no longer any content at the original URL. This is something that is can be set to be handled automatically by HttpURLConnection or another library like [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html). You will need to parse the status code, parse the headers, open a new socket to the response Location and get the page. Depending upon the exact requirements of your assignment, you will probably want to familiarize yourself with the [HTTP 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html), and the [HTTP 1.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) as well.

Comment: Ya laz that's true but i want to do this using socket as it is my assignment to parse the output received

Comment: I understand. Then you will need to properly interpret the HTTP status codes and response headers that the URL can return.

Comment: thanks that worked for me as changing the url to "xampp/index.php"

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is working, except maybe that you don't see the output because it's swamped by all the `null`s you print. You should stop the while after the first `null`.
 More generally, `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` are not the right classes for this job. Try this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 80);
    BufferedReader dIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    PrintStream dOut = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    dOut.println("GET /index.php HTTP/1.0");
    dOut.println();
    String str = null;
    do {
        str = dIn.readLine();
        System.out.println(str);
    } while (str != null);
}
```

Comment: Hey Flavio ya that is working but i m unable to see the whole page content. only "header" is shown to me and then "null" I have added the output to the question. please check this

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using socket directly to perform HTTP connection? This is fine exercise but it requires deep knowledge of internals of HTTP protocol. Why not just to use classes URL, and URLConnection?

```
BufferedReader dIn = new BufferedReader(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:80").openConnection().getInputStream());
do {
        str = dIn.readLine();
        System.out.println(str);
    } while (str != null);
}
```

Comment: Hey that is fine but i want to do this using sockets as it is my assignment